# PHP $_GET['id'] returns $1/.php/$1 from url rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

url: localhost/site/user-content-view.php?titleid=$1

when i use this url, the $titleid which i echoed $titleid=$_GET['titleid']; works fine and the output is a value returned and the current page works fine.

But when i use a pretty url i get this result 1202/.php/1202 or sometimes 1202.php and i dont any page like that and i'm not able to get the value alone .

pretty url : localhost/site/user-content-view/1202/

php code : href="user-content-view//"

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d   # i tried both SCRIPT_FILENAME and REQUEST_FILENAME but didnt work
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   # i tried both SCRIPT_FILENAME and REQUEST_FILENAME but didnt work
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^user-content-view/(.*)/$ ./user-content-view.php?titleid=$1
```

I want the value 1202 returned from get variable when i use pretty url

Im using php 7, mysql oops .....kindly help me please i didnt find any answer for this ....i need complete code for this and could you please explain what it does....thank you

Comment: Try to move your ^user-content-view/(.*)/$ above the previous rule and add [L] flag in the end of the line

Comment: Also... mysql tag is irrelevant here

Comment: i tried moving ^user-content-view line above the previous rule and i'm getting 500 internal server error with or without L flag

Comment: @CarlosCarucce Thank you for your help  buddy

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your help and time. I figured out myself actually here is my .htaccess file which worked

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^user-content-view/(.*)/$ ./user-content-view.php?titleid=$1 [L]



Options -Indexes


RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This helped me in getting the titleid 1202 which i wanted to the question which i asked... thank you all